# Python: random matrix from array

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I would like to generate from a vector that for simplicity we can call "serie1" another vector of dimension 1000x1 where each element of this new vector is the sum of j random elements of the vector "serie1".

I was thinking about creating a random matrix from the vector of dimension 1000xj and them sum horizontally.

How would you suggest to do in Python?

In order to get a random vector I could do

```
Vector=np.random.choice(serie1, 1000, replace=True)
```

but I would not know how to proceed and if there is an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
vector = np.random.choice(serie1, (1000, j), replace=True).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

Note that this is with replacement.

For not too large j an acceptance-rejection scheme could be applied to eliminate repeats.

```
def accept_reject(serie1, j):
    efficiency_ratio = 2 # just a guess
    M = len(serie1)
    accept_rate = np.prod(np.linspace(1-(j-1)/M, 1, j))
    n_draw = int(1000 / accpet_rate + 4 * np.sqrt(1000*(1 - accept_rate)))
    if n_draw * j * efficiency_ratio > 1000 * M:
        return use_other_solution(serie1, j)
    raw = np.random.randint(0, M, (n_draw, j))
    raw.sort(axis=-1)
    raw = raw[np.all(np.diff(raw, axis=-1) > 0, axis=-1), :]
    if len(raw)>1000:
        raw = raw[:1000, :]
    elif len(raw)<1000:
        return use_other_solution(serie1, j)
    return serie1[raw].sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: This would create duplicate indices, right? I thought OP wanted  `j random elements` and by that I assumed `j` unique elements off `serie1`.

Comment: @Divakar well they have a `replace=True` in their code snippet. Btw. ingenious as it is are you sure your argpartition solution is correct in the sense of sampling correctly?

Comment: Well OP mnetioned : `In order to get a random vector ..but I would not know how to proceed `. Don't think that leads us to what was mentioned as the goal of the question. Added a section in my post on the sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Base Python

```
from random import sample
vector = [sum(sample(serie1, j)) for _ in range(1000)]
```

With Numpy to enable replacement

```
import numpy as np
vector = [sum(np.random.choice(serie1, j, replace=True)) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Comment: I guess that in this case it is not allowed for replacement=true

Comment: That's right. So with replacement: `vector = [sum(np.random.choice(serie1, j, replace=True)) for _ in range(1000)]`

Comment: So, if both your solution and Paul's one are both correct these two:
            `Vector = [sum(np.random.choice(serie1, N, replace=True)) for _ in range(1000000)]`
and
            `Vector = np.random.choice(serie1, (1000000, N), replace=True).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)`
should yield the some result

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is getting `j` unique elements for `1000` rows. We can't use `np.random.choice(.....replace=True)` directly there as then we won't have `j` unique elements. To solve our case, one vectorized approach would be to use a random matrix of shape `(1000,len(input_array))`, perform `argsort` along the second axis and get `j` unique indices per row, then index into the input array with it and finally sum along the second axis.

To implement it, we would have two approaches -

```
def app1(serie1, j, N=1000):
    idx = np.random.rand(N,serie1.size).argsort(1)[:,:j]
    return serie1[idx].sum(1)
```

Using efficient `np.argpartition` for selecting random `j` elements and  then `np.take` for efficient indexing  -

```
def app2(serie1, j, N=1000):
    idx = np.random.rand(N,serie1.size).argpartition(j,axis=1)[:,:j]
    return np.take(serie1, idx).sum(1)
```

Sample run to demo creating the indices `idx` -

```
In [35]: serie1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(20))

In [36]: idx = np.random.rand(1000,serie1.size).argsort(1)[:,:5]

In [37]: idx
Out[37]: 
array([[16, 13, 19,  0, 15],
       [ 7,  4, 13, 15, 14],
       [ 8,  3, 15,  1,  9],
       ..., 
       [11, 15, 17,  4, 19],
       [19,  0,  3,  7,  9],
       [10,  1, 19, 12,  6]])
```

**Verifying uniform random sampling -**

```
In [81]: serie1 = np.arange(20)

In [82]: j = 5

In [83]: idx = np.random.rand(1000000,serie1.size).argsort(1)[:,:j]

In [84]: np.bincount(idx.ravel())
Out[84]: 
array([250317, 250298, 250645, 249544, 250396, 249972, 249492, 250512,
       249968, 250133, 249622, 250170, 250291, 250060, 250102, 249446,
       249398, 249003, 250249, 250382])
```

Having fairly equal counts across the length of `20` elems in the input array, I think its pretty uniformly distributed.

**Runtime test -**

```
In [140]: serie1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(20))

In [141]: j = 5

# @elcombato's soln
In [142]: %timeit [sum(sample(serie1, j)) for _ in range(1000)]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop

# Posted solutions in this post
In [143]: %timeit app1(serie1, j, N=1000)
     ...: %timeit app2(serie1, j, N=1000)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 943 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 870 µs per loop
```

Comment: Ok, nice answer but I get _ValueError: kth(=1300) out of bounds (800)_
for everyone of the 1000 simulations I have to sum 1300 elements in my specific case (so j=1300) taken randomly from the array series1 which has 800 elements

Comment: @Klapaucius So, you are supposed to take `1300` elements out off an array that has `800` elements? So, you are okay with some of those elements being duplicated?

Comment: @Klapaucius Then, I guess Paul Panzer's solution would be the one to solve your case.